# inApp Purchase in iPhone application to get book from iBook store

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase, storekit, ibooks

I am working in one iPhone application in which I need to add inApp Purchase functionality. Now in the inApp Purchase I need to add around 20 books which are already listed in iBook store. Now when I pay using inApp purchase, the purchased book from iBook store can be directly come in my application. Is it possible to do in iPhone application that can get the book from iBook store.

If anyone know this thing please help me out. I haven't seen any stuff related to this thing but really interesting thing to implement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not possible. In App Purchase is for creating your own store within your own application. It's not designed to add other people's stores in your apps.

Comment: But can we try once. Because iBooks is also the part of apple by the way. What do you think?

Comment: I think you'd be wasting your time! Even assuming that you can get the IAP bit working, how are you going to display the ebook? There are no APIs to do that either.

Comment: So, ebook is different from PDF. But don't they seems like PDF?